# Self invoking function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

I have a self invoking function like this:

```
var f = (function f(){ return "123"; }, 
         function g(){ return 2; },
         function h(){ return "test"; })();

typeof f;
```

`typeof f` is always the type of what is returned in the last function definition. Like if `h` is last, then it is `"string"`, but if I remove `h` and have `g` as last, then `"number"`.

Could someone explain why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'self-invoking function' - you have a series of functions, the last one of which (h) is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down.

The comma operator in Javascript evaluates several expressions, and returns the last one:

```
>>> "a", 1
1
>>> 1, "a"
"a"
```

So when you take three anonymous functions and string them together with commas, it evaluates to the last one:

```
>>> (function f(){ return "123"; }, function g(){ return 2; }, function h(){ return "test"; })
function h(){ return "test"; }
```

Evaluating that result executes the function, returning `"test"`.

Whichever function is last in the comma-separated list will be executed, and decide the overall return value.

Comment: Comma is also used in variable declaration list where it has different semantics I.E `var a, b, c;`

Comment: Yes. This is the comma operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 7):

Because the functions are separated by the `,` comma operator.

This evaluates the separated expressions, and returns the result of the *last* expression.

```
var x = ("a", "b", "c");

console.log(x); // "c"
```

So in your case, the last function is returned, as the result of the enclosing `()` group, and that's the one invoked by the trailing `()` function call.

```
   // result from group---v   v---invoked
var f = (func1, func2, func3)()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `comma` operator returns the last item. What you are doing is like:

```
var f = function(){}, function(){}, "string";
```

Which will make `f` a string, because only the last function is being called.